# Magento 2: Force Sign-In not working

Tags: magento2, customer, login, logout, token

I'm already logged in the frontend of my website.

Then I go to **Admin -> Customers -> Edit My Customer** & Click on **Force Sign-In**

It gives below error

> This customer has no tokens.

The user should be logged out from the frontend. Correct?

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4718

Required to use https://marketplace.magento.com/bitexpert-magento2-force-customer-login.html ?

Does it relates to oAuth?

Answer (score 5):

Had the same question while reading Magento User Guide when first saw this button. And here is the answer from the guide:

"Revokes the OAuth access tokens that are associated with the customer
account. This can be used only with customer accounts that have been
assigned OAuth tokens as part of a Web API integration. To learn more,
see: OAuth-based authenication.

Standard customer accounts created from the storefront or from the
Admin do not have OAuth tokens."

Hope this helps.